# Selenium IDE: Copy Image Location for further use

Tags: url, selenium, copy, selenium-ide

I'd like to store the URL of a variable image I have tried using `|storeText | xpath=/`  but it didn't work.

Comment: could you provide details on your problem? I mean a piece of your code that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use store attribute command for eg

put your x path in place of `//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]`
`<tr><td>open</td><td></td><td>gmail.com</td></tr><tr><td>storeAttribute</td><td>//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/img/@src</td><td>s</td>
</tr><tr><td>echo</td><td>${s}</td><td></td>/tr>`
accept the answer if its work for you